# Where Can I Give Feedback on Ubuntu?

Tags: testing, brainstorm

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 Beta 2. Is there a way, or a place, to give feedback on this system? Not file bugs, just give feedback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is. Go to [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=394). Specifically, that link will take you to the 'Natty Narwhal Testing and Discussion' sub-forum. People are always very happy to hear what you think about betas etc. in that sub-forum.

For ideas on how it could be improved, go to [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not looking to "gripe," I'm just a "noob" that wants to contribute! :)

Comment: No not at all mate. I hope the answer didn't come across the wrong way. It's very useful to have people share their thoughts in both of these places. Sorry once again if I worded this harshly. Not my intention at all. :)

Comment: Oh not at all, just letting you know I want to be "constructive!"

Comment: Ubuntu Brainstorm says, "You'll get new abilities as beget to know you" but they'll never "get to know me" because posting anything is not an ability I have yet earned!  I might try the other place.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

The [Natty Narwhal Testing and Discussion Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=394) is probably a good place for you to look. Although it's not regularly read by the Ubuntu developers it's a good place to discuss your views on 11.04.