# Where to suggest user experience enhancements?

Tags: gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where Can I Give Feedback on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36809/where-can-i-give-feedback-on-ubuntu)

where to report improvements for some applications that have features which can be enhanced. Current behavior of such a feature should be working exactly as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ayatana Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana) comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

Many programs maintain their own bug tracker database, and these are generally the best places for not just feature requests but also bug reports.  Many are documented at launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/bugtrackers , but use your google-fu to find others.